# Deleting an entity that's not tracked by DataServiceContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

How do I delete an entity that is not tracked by DataServiceContext. For instance, I have an object of my entity in the client side and I want to delete it. I know this particular object is already present inside the database in server side, but it is not inside the DataServiceContext entity tracker (one of the reason could be this object was not added by my client). How do i delete this object. Kindly help me

Comment: Can you do it by action/function? For action/function, you can refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/12/08/function-amp-action-in-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4-0-type-scenario.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Functions are my last option. Is there any other way to issue a delete request , so that I can use the Delete API in the server?

Comment: Or is there a way to populate the objects (by fetching them from server) into DataServiceContext entity tracker ?

Answer (score 3):

[Answering my own question]

This is how I am doing at present. Let's say My Entity is as below

```
class Book
{
   public string ISBN {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I want to delete a book whose ISBN (**key** property) is "AXBX".

```
var container = new Container(new Uri("http://localhost/MyApp/odata"));
var book = new Book(){ISBN = "AXBX"}
container.AttachTo("Books", book); // add object to entity tracker
container.DeleteObject(book);
container.SaveChanges();
```